# Mapbox Geocoding language

Tags: geocoding, mapbox

The Mapbox API supports geocoding requests fine, but I always get the results in English. I'd like to be able to get results in a specific language.

For the Mapbox.js API, it's possible to display the map in a different language (by changing style), but I can't find a way to translate geocoding requests correctly.

For example, if I pass in the city 'Gent', I would expect to see that it's in province Oost-Vlaanderen and country België. However, I get 'Gent, Oost-Vlanderen, Belgium'.
This would be done using a request like: https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/Gent.json?country=be&access_token=MYACCESSTOKEN

Is there a way to get the correctly translated result? Perhaps using a setting or extra parameter?

Answer (score 2):

The localized names that I see in Streets-v8 (and likely in mapbox.places) are `name_en`, `name_es`, `name_fr`, `name_ru`, & `name_zh`.

This looks like you'll need to file a feature request with Mapbox, at least you may be able to have support for `name_fr`.

I like to use the [Mapbox Command Line Interface](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-cli-py) to see the responses from the Mapbox querys.  This particular query gives a response of `"place_name": "Gent, Oost-Vlanderen, Belgium",`

```
mapbox-cli>   mapbox geocoding 'Gent' --country be
```

I also tried `Ghent` in the query, but still received English

The town shows as Ghent in the [Mapbox language switch example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/language-switch/).

Comment: Hm, I guess it's not really an option then :-( Either I file a feature request with Mapbox and hope for the best, or I set up my own geocoder, like Photon: https://photon.komoot.de/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a solution has been implemented!

Just pass in a language field on the initialization object like so:

```
var geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({ language: 'es' }); //change lang to spanish
```

Got it from these docs: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/blob/master/API.md#mapboxgeocoder